# angularjs changing factory object shared between controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

Is it possible to update the scope variable that points to a factory object, after the factory object is updated?
If there are 2 angular controllers which share a factory object, if one of the controllers changes the factory object, it is not reflected in the scope variable of the other controller.

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/zjm0mo10/
The result will be

"Factory foo.bar is 555" instead of

"Factory foo.bar is 666"

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory('testFactory', function(){
return {
    foo: {bar:555},
}               
});

function HelloCtrl($scope, testFactory)
{
    $scope.bar = testFactory.foo.bar;
    $scope.clickme = function()
    {
        alert("testFactory.foo.bar "+testFactory.foo.bar);
        $scope.$apply();
    }
}

function GoodbyeCtrl($scope, testFactory)
{
    testFactory.foo.bar = 666;
}

<html>
<div ng-controller="HelloCtrl">
    <p>Factory foo.bar is {{bar}}</p>
    <button ng-click="clickme();">btn</button>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your scope properties to `testFactory.foo`, eg

```
$scope.foo = testFactory.foo;
```

and

```
<p>Factory foo.bar is {{foo.bar}}</p>
```

That way, the scoped property will reference `testFactory.foo` which remains intact (not overwritten).

Also, you need to remove `$scope.$apply()` from `clickme()`. `ng-click` already triggers a digest cycle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zjm0mo10/1/

Comment: Thank you! Works as you suggested. Is it because when $scope.foo=testFactory.foo.bar it actually does not point to the memory location of testFactory.foo object since bar is a primitive?

Comment: @isgQ it's more that when you assign a new value to `testFactory.foo.bar`, any prior references are lost

Comment: @Phil I have a factory that returns multiple attributes such as name, email, etc. In a function my controller I am trying to update the value of the factoryService.email but later on it is showing empty. Any reason why this happens and how can I handle it? Is there a specific way to update the factory object?