# angularjs: controllers not sharing data, using a service

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have these controllers and service:

```
  angular.module('myApp', []);

  angular.module('myApp').factory('ShareService', function() {
    var delivery = {};
    delivery.name = "";
    delivery.setName = function(n){
      delivery.name = n;
    }
    return delivery;
  });


  angular.module('myApp').controller('controller2', function (ShareService) {
    this.name = ShareService.name;
  });


  angular.module('myApp').controller('controller1', function (ShareService) {
    this.setName = function (){
      ShareService.setName ("any name");
    };
  });
```

and the html:

```
<body ng-controller="controller1 as ctrl1">

 <button ng-click="ctrl1.setName()">Click Me</button>

 <div ng-controller="controller2 as ctrl2">
   <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl2.name">
 </div>

</body>
```

Why clicking the button doesn't update the input with the text `"any name"` What's wrong here? I have no clue. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs changing factory object shared between controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642625/angularjs-changing-factory-object-shared-between-controllers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into an issue with the difference between [copied by value vs copied by reference.](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_02.htm)

Particularly, this line of code:

```
this.name = ShareService.name;
```

Means you are actually copying the value of `ShareService.name` but not the actual reference to it because it is a primitive.

If you really want to share the exact same value, then you need a reference to an object, instead of the primitive value. You could bind directly to the `ShareService` instance if you wanted:

```
this.shareService = ShareService;

ng-model="ctrl2.shareService.name"
```

But that feels a little funny to me.

Another alternative is to create a "model" object of some kind on your `ShareService` and copy a reference to that into your controller instead.

```
var delivery = {
   shared: {name:""}
};

delivery.setName = function(n){
  delivery.shared.name = n;
}
return delivery;

this.shared = ShareService.shared;

ng-model="ctrl2.shared.name"
```

This would all have the effect of making sure that the bound property is always pointing to the same shared value, and not just a copy.

Comment: thanks! I implemented it (2nd alternative) but I'm still trying to digest the problem. I spent hours trying to find some clue. No error/warning is issued on the console.

Comment: @jasa - Yup, and there wouldn't be either. The code is perfectly valid, but not necessarily correct. Reading up on the passed by value vs. passed by reference will really help out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a plunker with a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/i5jPFl717RtkMw0MwVTZ?p=preview

The thing is that `this.name = ShareService.name;` is copying by value and not by reference.

A workaround could be to define your `delivery.name` as an Object and not as a string. So that you can copy it by reference.

```
app.factory('ShareService', function() {
  var delivery = {};
  delivery.name = {
    value: "default"
  };
  delivery.setName = function(n) {
    delivery.name.value = n;
  }
  return delivery;
});

app.controller('controller1', function(ShareService) {
  this.setName = function() {
    ShareService.setName("modified");
  };
});

app.controller('controller2', function(ShareService) {
  this.name = ShareService.name;
});
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="controller2 as ctrl2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl2.name.value">
  </div>
```